# Motorcycle Database (make/model/prod year)

Tags: data-modeling

This is more of a resource question rather than technical one.

I am building a website for a client who needs to categorize photos (motorcycles) and I am looking for a database of models/years/production year.

If anyone knows where I can find such database please let me know.

Comment: The tags are misleading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link that I was able to find for you. From my experience, it's really hard to find anything free that deals with vehicle database references because of the ever changing makes and models.

[DataOneSoftware.com](http://dataonesoftware.com/index.php/solutions/datasolutions/basicdata)

If the above website doesn't work out for you, then another possiblity would be to see if you can find some of the old VIN lookup books out there and see if there is someway to get a download link or a CD copy of their information.

Good luck on your project.

Comment: Good resource but I would prefer to have the ability to download the database instead of using a service. Anyway, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: Eeyore--DataOne Software does allow you to download the database instead of using the web service.

Comment: I got an export of a 2017 database if anyone's looking for it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1s1yynwgGqqCktq7FxOCOs4ApGDiSN_6pK45V7_md93g/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you very much @zanderwar

Answer (score 3):

Here is a database I put together for a Motorcycle website I was working on.

[Motorcycle & Scooter Database](http://www.e-junkie.com/cybercoder/product/441487.php#Motorcycle+and+Scooter+Database), Years 1970-2010, 16,000+ records

Answer (score 0):

You can automate an image search (through google image for example) for every make and model you got in the database. This method is error prone and the images have to be checked also manually to see that they are correct. But its an idea.
Also note copyright material and other things like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another make-model-year database from here: http://allmotodatabase.com

Not perfect, but very good if you need moto make-model-year DB for some project, plus it contains some additional info (not available for all models though)

Answer (score -1):

This came up when I was searching for one, I decided to scrape bikez.com, it's not complete (atm) but the scraper can be found https://github.com/ibash/bikez_scraper